# How to count the occurences of multiple patterns in a long string?

Tags: php, regex

I have a long string, and an array of country names. So the array looks something like this:

```
array('Afghanistan', 'Bulgaria', 'United States', 'Bulgaria', ...)
```

I need to count the number of times each country appears in the string. 
Is there a quick and nifty way of doing this, i.e., some kind of magical [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) which receives an array of patterns, or must I iterate through all countries?

Comment: for the record, an array is not a string. these are two very different questions.

Comment: I believe he is aware of that, he has an array an a large string.

Comment: Be careful for sentences like: 'In Bulgaria people are called Bulgarians'. You might count the word 'Bulgaria' twice while only once might be desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
$country_names = array('Afghanistan', 'Bulgaria', 'United States', ...);
$country_names_preg = "/(" . implode("|", $country_names) . ")/";
preg_match_all($country_names_preg, $long_string, $matches);

//$matches will contain all of the country matches.
$echo "found: " . implode(", ", $matches);

// There would ideally be a check to make sure that $matches had something in it!
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd just use a hash table (associative array) and loop through your countries:

```
// Count:
$country_names = array('Afghanistan', 'Bulgaria', 'United States', ...);
$country_count = array();
foreach ($country_names as $name) {
  $country_count[$name]++;
}

// Then display:
foreach ($country_names as $name) {
  echo "Found " . $country_count[$name] . " occurrences of $name.\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is what he ia after... I think he has a string with plenty of other text it in and wants to count the occurance of each country in that string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something blazingly fast (but not quick to implement), consider [Aho Corasick's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick_algorithm). [Here](http://www.scriptlance.com/projects/1253101154.shtml)'s an implementation in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Try using substr_count https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

```
$yourtmplongstring = strtolower($yourlongstring);
# the above will solve any case sensitive issues
$country_names = array('Afghanistan', 'Bulgaria', 'United States', ...);
$country_count = array();
foreach ($country_names as $name) {
    $occurances = substr_count($name, $yourtmplongstring );
    $country_count[$name] = $occurances;
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Thanks, that would work - but it's case sensitive. So if I have BULGARIA in the text, It's not going to work.

Comment: Please check my edit as this would solve your case sensitive issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with one call, but while you're iterating through substr_count() may be faster than preg_* for this purpose.